# SUMIFS with INT in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been working with Google sheets for the last couple of months. I am trying to do the following function:

```
=SUMIFS(INT(J11:J15),I11:I15,L11)
```

i.e. I want to sum up only the integer part of the range J11:J15 if and only if I11:I15 matches L11.
The error message which I get is **Argument must be a range**

I want to do this sum without creating a new column with the integer part alone(if at all).

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
=sumproduct(I11:I15=L11, int(J11:J15))
```

or

```
=sum(filter(INT(J11:J15),I11:I15=L11) )
```

Answer (score 0):

As additional (alternative) other than sumproduct and filter:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(sum(if(I11:I15=L11, INT(J11:J15))))
```

or

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(sum((I11:I15=L11) * INT(J11:J15)))
```

But I prefer to suggest you to use sumproduct, because it's more easy